# how to change checkbox style in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a checkbox in Qt that I want to change its style from the one in the picture below:

[image]

to the one in the picture below:

[image]

What I've tried so far is:

```
QCheckBox::indicator::checked
{
background-color: rgb(24, 144, 255);
indicator: white;
}
```

result:

[image]

the check inside checkbox disappears

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800541/how-to-change-the-color-of-tick-in-qcheckbox-widget

Comment: setting `color: white;` makes somewhat similar to your requirement.

Comment: @sumit_smk this didn't work I also tried It before...

Comment: @HARSHMITTAL so if I'm not wrong what I understood is that it's can't be done without using images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can either use an image or a font like [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) to be loaded. For example, the QML example below uses the checkmark unicode as the text property. You can use a `FontLoader` to load the font or see if you have a system font that has a checkmark.

```js
FontLoader {
   id: fontAwesome
   source: "qrc:<path>/fontawesome.otf"
}

CheckDelegate {
    contentItem: Label {
        ...
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        ...
        color: "white"
    }

    indicator: Rectangle {
        ...
        Text {
            text: checked ? "\uf00c" : ""
            font.family: fontAwesome.name // Setup from FontLoader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the usage of an image but if it's like so I'm afraid that I have no other choice

Comment: The font unicode style is probably the most convenient as it supports SVG and keeps your package size small. Or else the image will have to be embedded within the executable as a resource. Plus you might use the font in other places as well for nice button design.